# Spring amqp dead letter exchange with multiple queue bind

Tags: java, spring-boot, rabbitmq, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

In my app , using two queues which are binded with one exchange with a key a.*.* 
Any message coming with matching with this  key regex will go to both the queues.

Case 2 : I am trying to implement delay message and max retries in case consumer's business exception using dead letter exchange mechanism.

Problem case suppose one of the queue's consumer's through business exception.... It will go the dlx and then to the main exception..... Then from the main exception.... Message is going to both the queues. This is the issue which I am facing ..... I want that retry message should go to that  queue only from where the consumer exception occurred.

Now in my cases retry message is going to all the queues and creating duplicate messages.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a second, queue-specific, binding for each queue; then configure each DLQ with that specific routing key...

`x-dead-letter-exchange=mainExchange`
`x-dead-letter-routing-key=retryMainQ1`

Of course, you need 2 DLQs.

Comment: For development use, I have created multiple queues and multiple DLQs as you mention, when channel closed the main queue is deleting because I have specified expire time and auto-delete so if there is no consumer's, queue will delete automatically but not DLQ, how should I delete queue when worker queue is deleted?

Comment: Don't ask new questions in comments on 4 year-old answers. You could enable the event exchange plugin to receive queue deletion events, https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/current/reference/html/#broker-events

Comment: actually i am using nodejs ampplib, the issue is for only for development env but not production (production contains one worker queue and one DLQ), i can specify expire time for DLQ but i don't know when worker queue is deleted (if 5 devs working, 5 worker queues will create along with 5 DLQ's, when developer close his connection, worker queue is deleting but not DLQ). anyway thanks for your suggestion

Comment: My second comment was for a different answer; sorry.